# Office 365 SharePoint 2013 Send email with attachments

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, office-365

I need to send Email with attachments in Office 365 SharePoint 2013. We cannot do this using the sharepoint designer workflow.

Is there any way to call exchange web service from javascript and achieve this ? We want to avoid using provider/azure hosted apps to do this.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to add a link to the item which has the attachement as a workaround if you don't want to add third party tools or Azure/Provider hosted Apps.

In your e-mail template **Define E-mail Message** add a Link and edit the link with String Builder to get a direct link to the item. It's not an optional solution but it fairly easy for a user to click on the link to find the attachement on the item.

[image]